# LibGdx MapObjects empty on valid tilemap

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled, tmx, tmxtiledmap

I am currently using libgdx and it's box2d extension to make an open world platformer. I wanted to render a world from a tmx tilemap, and add physics from it. The tilemap renders fine (using `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer`), but when I tried to add phyiscs using the following code nothing happened.

```java
public void renderPhysicsMap(TiledMap map, World world, int layer, int tileSize) {
        TiledMapTileLayer mapLayer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(layer);
        MapObjects mapObjects = mapLayer.getObjects();
        for (MapObject mapObject : mapObjects) {
            Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) mapObject).getRectangle();
            BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
            bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
            Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
            PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
            shape.setAsBox((rect.width/2)/tileSize, (rect.height/2)/tileSize);
            Fixture fixture = body.createFixture(shape, 0.0f);
            fixture.setFriction(0.1f);
            Vector2 center = new Vector2();
            rect.getCenter(center);
            body.setTransform(center.scl(1/tileSize), 0);
        }
    }
```

After some debugging (running `mapObjects.getCount()`) I found that the size was 0. This is odd, because I know this is a valid tilemap (I can render it just fine). Would anyone know why this is?